# How can I disable "Pointer can be controlled using the keypad" function on Laptop?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, laptop, numpad

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 on Desktop but Ubuntu originally was installed on laptop. Numeric keypad on my keyboard was set as mouse moving and mouse button. No matter how I toggle Num lock and change the QWERTY to AZERTY and change back, I can't use numeric keypad probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you!

Open `System Settings` by going to `Session Indicator` in Unity panel.

[image]

In system settings open `Universal Access`.

[image]

Under `Pointing and Clicking` tab turnoff the `Control the pointer using the keypad`.

[image]

Comment: thx,
I forget to try U.Access Section~